# Reveal Column by clicking on the Cell in it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub (on WorkSheet) which enlarge Column when I click on the Cell. The problem is I can't back original size of the column when I leaving it.

I tried use some default parameters, but this end with error.

```
Then rngDEwidh.Columns.ColumnWidth = rngDEwidh.Columns.ColumnWidth
Then rngDEwidh.Columns.ColumnWidth = xlNone
Then rngDEwidh.Columns.ColumnWidth = ActiveCell.width
```

Here is a sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Static rngDEwidh As Range
    If Not rngDEwidh Is Nothing Then rngDEwidh.Columns.ColumnWidth = xlNone
    Set rngDEwidh = Target
    rngDEwidh.Columns.ColumnWidth = 25
End Sub
```

Error when using xlNone and its ok if I use any value (10 for instance). But I need original size of the column.

Comment: Do the columns hava standard width? If not you would need to save the current widths of all relevant columns and access those to restore the columns to their original width. This could be achieved in many ways.

Comment: The columns have different width.

Comment: Sacrifice two cells in the columns (bottom?) and refer to these cells holding widths when you enter/exit a cell in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is I can't back original size of the column when I leaving it.

Is this what you are trying?. This stores the previous width and column number in a variable.

```
Dim prevWidth As Long
Dim prevCol As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If prevWidth <> 0 And prevCol <> 0 Then
        Columns(prevCol).ColumnWidth = prevWidth
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    prevWidth = Target.ColumnWidth
    prevCol = Target.Column
    Columns(prevCol).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: _____Great_____

Comment: What I had in mind at first, seeing this I'm thinking > `Dictionary`. Would that be a reasonable solution in your opinion? + btw =)

Comment: Yes you can solve it using a dictionary but it seems like an overkill in this case. storing data in 2 variables is my easier :)

Comment: Dear Siddharth Rout, last time you've provided a good solution which I use till now and it works fine. But how to do this for a specific fields only, for example "A" and "E" columns ? I tried to remake script a little but unsuccessfully.

Comment: I just published  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69537198/reveal-whole-column-for-a-and-e-columns-only-when-the-cell-is-selected-and-back

Comment: The interesting thing - I can do a lot of things in powershell but vba is differ :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example where I sacrifice the TOP two rows that holds width for active and inactive columns:

[image]

You can obviously pick any row, maybe even use a named range in case you add/delete rows. But this is the code I used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range
For Each cl In Range("A1:E1")
    Set rng = Intersect(cl.EntireColumn, Target.Columns)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        cl.ColumnWidth = cl(1)
    Else
        cl.ColumnWidth = cl(2)
    End If
Next cl

End Sub
```

---

[image]

---

***EDIT***

Another interesting thing to do is to create a `Dictionary` upon activating the specific sheet. Fill that dictionary with the columnwidth of each column in the specified range. The rest is a small adaptation of the code I showed above.

```
Public dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

For Each cl In Range("A1:E1")
    dict.Add cl.Column, cl.ColumnWidth
Next cl

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

For Each cl In Range("A1:E1")
    Set rng = Intersect(cl.EntireColumn, Target.Columns)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        cl.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Else
        cl.ColumnWidth = dict(cl.Column)
    End If
Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Very interesting.

Comment: @OlegZolotarenko, no worries. Just edited the answer to include another option as well using a `Dictionary` based on the thought of storing settings in a variable.