# Reveal whole column for A and E columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on the code from [Reveal Column by clicking on the Cell in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58162833/reveal-column-by-clicking-on-the-cell-in-it) which reveals whole column when the cell is selected. It works fine. I tried this for A and E columns, but I can't do it.

```
Dim prevWidth As Long
Dim prevCol As Long
    
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If prevWidth <> 0 And prevCol <> 0 Then
        Columns(prevCol).ColumnWidth = prevWidth
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    prevWidth = Target.ColumnWidth
    prevCol = Target.Column
    Columns(prevCol).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It works fine". If its working fine, what are you not able to do?

Comment: Did you paste the code into the worksheet module?

Comment: Dear Siddharth Rout, I mean the code should work only in Columns A and E. For examble in column B this code should not work and the column's width should be constant :). As I understand it's not Intersect method. Now when I leave column A and go to B, nothing change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will work for any column. To make it work for only column `A` and `E`, you need to use [INTERSECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect)

In the case the above link dies

[image]

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Dim prevWidth As Long
Dim prevCol As Long
    
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A,E:E")) Is Nothing Then
        If prevWidth <> 0 And prevCol <> 0 Then Columns(prevCol).ColumnWidth = prevWidth
    
        On Error Resume Next
        prevWidth = Target.ColumnWidth
        prevCol = Target.Column
        Columns(prevCol).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]